# Can I catch an event when application is uninstalled?

Tags: react-native

I am building an application with React-Native.

I need to notice to my server when the application is uninstalled. Is there a way to catch an event when a user uninstall the app?

Comment: Sorry, this is not possible. It's not a limitation of React Native - neither Apple or Google give you this metric. You can track your app install numbers in Google Analytics and iTunes Connect, but I believe neither will give you a simple answer either.