# react native how run code if uninstall app

Tags: react-native, push-notification, uninstallation, onesignal

Is there a way to run code (for example call an api to delete some data automatically) if I delete the app?

To be more specific, to make a call to an api to delete push information if the user delete the app without loging out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126762/can-i-catch-an-event-when-application-is-uninstalled):

> Sorry, this is not possible. It's not a limitation of React Native - neither Apple or Google give you this metric. You can track your app install numbers in Google Analytics and iTunes Connect, but I believe neither will give you a simple answer either.

Comment: I dind't found that answer, I supposed that.